# How do I resize my debian partition?

Tags: debian, setup, sd-card, partition

I've seen advice [here for resizing](http://elinux.org/RPi_Easy_SD_Card_Setup), which is fine if you have another linux distribution to work with.

How can I do resize the partition otherwise? Are there any Windows tools for example?

Comment: Do you want to resize the partition using the RPi or using another computer?

Comment: just install ubuntu linux in a virtual box on your windows machine :)

Answer (score 3):

The [e2fsprogs](http://e2fsprogs.sourceforge.net/) package can be installed on Windows (via [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/)) and Mac OS X (via [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/)).

You can then use `resize2fs` as described in the linked wiki page.

I have not been able to resize the image on the SD card directly under Windows, however you can back up the linux partition to a file (as described in [another question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/313/54)), run `resize2fs` on the file, then restore the enlarged partition from the file back to the partition on the SD card.

Comment: Have you actually tried this? I don't see how it would work on an image file.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing is to image the OS onto a SD card.

Then using MiniTool Partition Wizard you can very easily change the size of partitions on the SD card.

There is also an option in raspi-config that will set the OS to use the whole of the SD card, if that's what your after