# Backup Image of SD Card

Tags: sd-card, backup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I backup my Raspberry Pi?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/311/how-do-i-backup-my-raspberry-pi)

While messing around with my RPi it likely that I'm going to want to revert to a previous position (but not revertingall the way back to the original debian image).

For example, say I installed mysql, but then decided that I want to try using sqllite instead.

Rather than a messy and possible incomplete uninstallation, it would be easier just to revert to an image of my SD card, taken prior to installing mysql.

What would be the best way of taking such an image of my SD card, and then reverting to it later? This would be different to saving just settings - I want a full image of the SD card.

(my particular distro is the debian wheezy beta if that helps).

Comment: Yes, exact duplicate.

Comment: As this is a duplicate, shouldn't it be merged with the other question?

Comment: @zenbike: Only if the answers here add to the other question. I suspect they largely duplicate info.