# dd entire SD card to new one

Tags: sd-card, backup

I'm going to clone my 8GB SD card to my 16GB one. My current SD card 8GB Kingston SDHC Class 4, and my new one is 16 GB SanDisk Extreme 45MB/s SDHC Class 10.

I've attempted using Win32 disk imager, however I get CRC errors after it has completed the `boot` partition. So therefore I want to attempt to use `dd` and see if it works at all. I've had some experience with `dd` and I've been able to mount the outputted data to a `.img` file and then of course mount that image file when needed to access it. Question is, how do I re-add all the files and folders to the new SD card exactly how it was on my old one?

For example, the output of `dd` will likely be `old.img`. Therefore, I know just simply coping `old.img` to the new SD card won't work. I need the entire contents *inside* `old.img` to be on the SD card.

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/942/40

Comment: Thank you @Jivings, the link you gave took me to another question which included a similar answer to what user60684 gave.

Answer (score 2):

Use this command:

`dd if=/dev/mmcblk0 of=/dev/mmcblk1 bs=4096 conv=notrunc, noerror`
This assumes mmcblk0 is the source SD card and mmcblk1 is the new one.

If you only have one SD slot you can make an image, which can also be used for backups.

`dd if=/dev/mmcblk0 of=backup-MM-DD-YYY.img conv=notrunc, noerror`
Swap SD cards then:

```
 dd if= backup-MM-DD-YYYY.img
   of=/dev/mmcblk0 conv=notrunc, noerror
```

`notrunc` means do not truncate the output file, `noerror` means to keep going if there is an error.

Boot into your new SD card and select expand file system on raspi-config.

Comment: I will give this a try and tick in due course if it works :-) thank you!

Answer (score 1):

CRC error when cloning SD card for RPi seem to be just Kingston SD cards issue - this can be found else where on the internet. DD (for Windows) does not work for me either - same CRC error like in Win32 Disk Imager. Try to use some "cloning" SW where you can ignore CRC check error - i.e. Partclone (http://www.partclone.org/usage/partclone.restore.php) - this one works for me or try Ghost2k3 - this one I did not try, but there is possibility to turn off CRC error check in the menu.

Answer (score 0):

Just use dd or the Window's disk imager to copy the image to the new card.

Then boot from the new card.

If you are using Raspbian you can then use raspi-config to expand the user partition to use the full card.

Comment: Please read the second paragraph of my question.

Comment: There are several parts to the paragraph.  What is your concern?

Comment: That I'm unable to use Win32 Disk Imager due to CRC errors.

Comment: If the SD card you are reading or writing is corrupt there's not much you can do apart from try several times.

Comment: Hence my efforts for attempting to use `dd`...

Comment: In case anybody comes across and interprets joan's message as the initial image creation... **IT IS NOT**... joan's comment is based on writing your backimage.iso *back* to your SD card. Reason why I'm commenting this is because without knowing that, you can completely erase the contents of your SD card otherwise.

Comment: Good point.  I've deleted the comment to prevent that happening.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when trying to copy a known working raspian SD card - win32 disk imager crashed with CRC errors. I was using a USB SD card reader. When I tried my laptop (DELL Core i3 Win 7 64bit) internal SD card reader it worked fine. I suggest you try a different SD card reader.

Comment: Nice suggestion, although my laptop does have an internal SD card reader. My issue is identical to yours though; Raspbian works perfectly, no issues, but unable to clone.