# How would I write a one-off boot script?

Tags: setup, software-development

I would like to run a script that would run only on the first boot. For example, Tom could use it to generate unique SSH certs in [How can I copy the same image to many SDs?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/1098/86).

I was thinking that I could get the script to delete itself, is this a good idea?

Comment: Boot scripts are handled differently by different distributions. So re-tagging with what distro you're using would be helpful.

Comment: I would have preferred a distro agnostic answer...

Comment: That would have to be a separate answer for each distro then.

Answer (score 3):

Why should it be a bad idea?
Check if your script was succesful and put as last command

```
rm -f $0
```

Comment: I couldn't think of a reason!

Comment: But check if everything went well. Raspbmc does not and tried to boot a zero-byte root filesystem

Answer (score 1):

Why not check if the output exists before you try to write it? Here is some pseudo-code:

```
if( file_exists( '/etc/myfile' ) ) {
    delete( $SELF );
    exit( 0 );

} else {
    create_file( '/etc/myfile' );
}
```

It makes sure your output exists before it deletes itself. This way, you can be (more) sure that your script did its job (or wasn't required for some reason).