# replicating one Raspberry Pi to many

Tags: linux, sd-card, windows

Is there any way to replicate one Raspberry Pi's OS and files to many?
I did a project on one raspberry pi by installing few additional packages, images and a python code, and it is working now. Bu i need 5 copies of same project.

How can i do this without doing all the installations and programming on other 4 RPis.

I tried to copy and paste sd card files, but my Linux Mint and Windows is not displaying sd card contents

Comment: The "duplicate" is a solution, but is a sledgehammer approach for 4 copies (and is quite dated). You can copy card images using `dd` or a SD Copier or use `rsync` (which is probably the fastest). The latest Raspbian can copy to a SD Card mounted in a reader. Unfortunately I can't add a detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

A more generic answer is to use dd or the "disk dump" utility. If you are doing this on a large scale there are sdcard dupelicators that can make many exact copies of other sdcards.

Answer (score 0):

The same SD card cloning tools you used to program the image in the first place can be used to take a copy from the SD card that's already set up: [How can I copy the same image to many SDs?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1098/how-can-i-copy-the-same-image-to-many-sds?rq=1)