# Using the argument bs with dd when backuping an SD card

Tags: boot, backup

I've seen [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/311/how-do-i-backup-my-raspberry-pi) on how to backup an SD-card. It's the same solution I would come up with myself; that is basically:

```
dd if=/dev/blabla of=/home/user/some_file.img`
```

But my question is if using the argument `bs=1M` makes any difference. It does when I'm writing to the card, so I suppose it does when I'm reading from it. Is my assumption correct? In the question I referred to earlier, it differs in different answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd_%28Unix%29#Block_size):

> A block is a unit measuring the number of bytes that are read,
> written, or converted at one time.
>
> ...
>
> For some uses of the dd command, block size may have an effect on performance. For example, when recovering data from a hard disk, a small block size will generally cause the most bytes to be recovered. For greater speed during copy operations, a larger block size may be used. When dd is used for network transfers, the block size may have an impact on packet size, depending on the network protocol used.

Comment: Oh! I suppose this site has a rule of not writing stuff like RTFM, but am I allowed to say that to myself? :-p

Comment: @NiclasNilsson It's fine. Sometimes we all need to be pointed in the right direction. And lots of people will learn something extra (myself included).