# How to repair my SD card installation?

Tags: raspbian

I have a Raspbian installation on which I installed a lot of stuffs.

A few weeks ago, I bought a Class10 16Gb card and cloned my raspbian installation from my old Class4 4Gb SD card to this new SD card.

I did not expand the old FS to the whole 16Gb partition (I planned to create another partition later but this is not a problem for me).

## The problem

Everything worked fine until yesterday:

- impossible to log-in using SSH
- after rebooting (connecting my TV screen and a keyboard) nothing happened
- since that, every time I connect my power supply, the screen flashes but nothing happens
- I tried to re-use my old Class4 SD: booting and running was OK
- Connecting my Class10 SD card to another linux machine:

  - IO errors
  - unable to perform any fsck (due to errors)

When I shutdown my RPi, I always use "shutdown -h now" command. Yesterday, my RPi was up and running since 4 days.

## What I already did

### Testdisk

I ran testdisk and it indicated some errors

```
check_FAT: Unusual number of reserved sectors 16 (FAT), should be 1.
Warning: number of heads/cylinder mismatches 255 (FAT) != 1 (HD)
Warning: number of sectors per track mismatches 63 (FAT) != 1 (HD)
 1 * FAT16 LBA                   8192     122879     114688 [RPIBOOT16G]
 2 P Linux                     122880    7829503    7706624
```

I did not write modification to the SD card using it.

### FS backup

I mounted my fs as read-only and tried to copy (cp -a) the whole files to another directory (this is because I made some changes since I cloned from Class4 to Class10 SD). Apparently, it finished without errors.

## What should I do now ?

Now I have a backup of my files, but I don't know how to repair the failing SD card.

Should I rewrite partition table ? But how (which partition size for /boot, other partition to add, create a new MBR and how) ?

So what should I do now to restore my Class10 SD card with the backup I made ?

What tools, what procedure should I use ?

Comment: how did you back up your class 4 card?
using 'dd' command you can easily make a 1:1 image from your card which results in a .img file

Comment: I know that, that is already used dd to clone it to the 16Gb card. What I want to know is how to recover my 16Gb backuped files.

Comment: Just too rule out the obvious how are you powering your Pi?

Comment: I have a 2000mA power output which seems to work fine (no problem since 6 months).

Comment: if your Class 10 card is still recognized and can be mounted, I don't think there's any problem. Corruption can happen and can (but not have to) lead to physical damage.

Comment: Are you overclocking your Pi?  I had major corruption on my class 10 card that turned out to be caused by overclocking. See http://elinux.org/RPiconfig#SD_Card_Usage_with_Overclocking for more details on that.  After restoring my SD card from a dd backup I noticed that there were SD write timeouts in syslog that were going unnoticed for some time. See [my SO question](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/12042/what-could-cause-the-ext4-root-file-system-to-become-unusable-after-a-reboot-or) for details on my issue.

Comment: Can't you just redo what you did when you originally cloned it?

Comment: @Gotschi: yes it can be mounted. But when I tried this, I had IO errors. But now it has not error anymore. I will retry to boot my RPi with it

Comment: @HeatfanJohn: no overclocking there

Comment: I made a new fsck on the corrupted volume. Although the first time, the fsck completed with errors, by now it said "disk clean" with no errors.

So I try booting again this morning with my class10 SD card and... it worked ! Maybe be it just needed to sleep for a night !

Comment: Maybe the fsck did not work the first time because I performed it on an old machine. The second time, I used a brand new Debian virtual machine.