# How to create regular backups of my PIs

Tags: backup

I have three Pis running in my local net and backup them on a regular base.

I just detected threads where people asked how to create a backup just in case something went wrong. I tried to answer in the threads - but I don't have enough credits to do so :-(

That's why I just post a link to a backup script which I use to backup my Pis. It's able to create dd, tar and rsync backups and to restore them. It's used by a lot of people already - primarily by German folks. Hope it's useful also for others :-) [raspibackup - Raspberry creates backups of itself](http://www.linux-tips-and-tricks.de/en/raspberry/303-pi-creates-automatic-backups-of-itself)

Comment: It's ok to answer your own question, but you shouldn't do it in the question part. Add it as an answer instead

Comment: If you invest a little time on the site you will soon have enough reputation to post an answer. Opening another question is not the way to handle a protected question. They only serve to segment important information.

Comment: Got it. Sorry. I don't mind if this question is deleted. I will append the same answer on http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/5427/can-a-raspberry-pi-be-used-to-create-a-backup-of-itself?rq=1 when I got enough credits.