# how to copy sd-card whithout copying the unallocated space

Tags: pi-4, sd-card, partition, resize

I have a **32Gb** SD card and I want to make a light copy of my os to make it work on a **16Gb** SDcard.

I wanted to copy just the allocated space so I used `gparted` to resize my **rootfs partition**.

[image]

after that I used `Disks` to create the image:

- I selected the rootfs partition
- there is an option under settings `Create partition image`

and now I have .img of the rootfs partition

I did the same for my boot partition.

is it the right way ? I have just one SD card so I couldn't test because I don't want to lose my data so I wanted to make sure that it is correct.

If I execute this everything will work fine ? I intend to resize the root partition after copying the .img

```
sudo dd bs=4M if=PiOSrootfs.img of=/dev/mmcblk0p2
sudo dd bs=4M if=PiOSboot.img of=/dev/mmcblk0p1
```

Thank you for helping

Comment: This question makes no sense. You claim to want to copy SD Cards but not have a second. You claim to have done impossible things.

Comment: Assuming your using Raspberry Pi OS, why not use the ‘SD Card Copier’ application?

Comment: @Milliways right now I just have a 32Gb SD card, and I don't want to lose my os .. I have also to test something on a fresh install of os . I forgot my 16Gb SD card so I don't have it now and I don't want to lose my time so I have to make a copy of my os before installing the new one on the 32GB SD card .. I want my copy size to be at maximum 16Gb ..

Comment: @CoderMike I am working on a lite version of os. is it possible to use it  ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Question:

> I have a 32Gb SD card and I want to make a light copy of my os to make it work on a 16Gb SDcard.

### Answer - use `image-backup`

Perhaps the easiest way to do this is with the `image-backup` utility - part of `image-utils`. If you are running RPi OS, `image-backup` has these advantages:

- `image-backup` may be done on a "live" system: no need to shut down the system, or unmount the device.
- `image-backup` is fast: **3min:55sec elapsed time** to create a bootable image on RPi 4B from a 32GB SD card; activities included in elapsed time:

  - Includes *interactive* dialog w/ `image-backup` & USB HDD I/O (USB-3 port).
  - Includes 3x `resize2fs` and `e2fsck` on the finished `ext4` partition - part of `image-backup`
  - On a RPi 3B: **13min:42sec** from a 16GB SD card to USB "thumb" drive (USB-2 port).
  - Elapsed times measured as follows:

  ```
  $ echo $(date) && sudo ./image-backup && echo $(date)
  ```
- `image-backup` produces a small raw image file:

  - image file contains *only* actual data on SD card - not the entire partition (à la `dd`)
  - 32GB GB SD card `-->` 4.05GB
    For comparison:

  ```
  $ df -h
  Filesystem             Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
  /dev/root               29G  5.0G   23G  18% /
  /dev/mmcblk0p1         256M   47M  209M  19% /boot
  ```
- `image-backup` produces an **.img** file that can be *flashed* to another SD card, USB drive, etc using common tools such as `etcher` and `rufus`.
- `image-backup` is free (no cost) and open sourced `bash` script.

As its name implies, the primary purpose of `image-backup` is making a **live backup** of an RPi. *Coincidentally*, it's also a good solution to **shrinking** the OS to fit on a smaller SD card.

You can [download a copy of `image-utils` from this location](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=332000) (see the link at the bottom of the original post) - or if you prefer using `git`, you can get a copy from this [GitHub repo](https://github.com/seamusdemora/RonR-RPi-image-utils). The instructions for using `image-backup` (in the `README` file) may be a bit fuzzy at first, but it's very simple to use. If you have problems, you can post questions to the author in the forum, or ask a specific question here.

### How will `image-backup` address my question?

Once you've *"installed"* it, you can make a complete backup of your entire system to an **image file**. By "**image file**", I mean a file that can be flashed to your (smaller) SD card using `etcher` or `rufus` (for example), and then booted in your RPi.

`image-backup` compresses the image file, and installing to a smaller (32GB->16GB) SD card will not be a problem based the info in your question.

### Show me how...

There is no *package* for `image-utils`, so `apt` cannot be used to install it. However, `image-utils` is just a collection of scripts (text files), and very easy to install; you may install manually, or via `git`:

#### Manual installation of `image-utils` on your RPi:

Open a terminal window (or via SSH) in your RPi, and from your home directory (`/home/pi`):

```bash
cd && mkdir image-utilities && cd image-utilities
wget -O image.zip "https://forums.raspberrypi.com/download/file.php?id=63044&sid=58c9d2d90272e5ae96c12a58a30731d9"
unzip ./image.zip 
chmod a+x image-*
```

#### ALTERNATIVELY, use `git` to d/l & `install`:

```bash
cd
git clone https://github.com/seamusdemora/RonR-RPi-image-utils
sudo install --mode=755 ./RonR-RPi-image-utils/image-* /usr/local/sbin
```

#### run `image-backup`

At this point, `image-backup` is ready to use, but you will need to have a USB drive mounted (or any drive under `/mnt`) as a destination for the image file it will create. Once your USB drive is mounted, you may create the image file as follows:

```bash
sudo image-backup
```

- **`image-backup` will prompt you for the options needed:**

  ```
  Image file to create? /mnt/Passport2TB/img_backups/20210113_Pi4B_imagebackup.img
  ```

> NOTE: A full path specification to the image file you want to create. The drive must be mounted under `/mnt` or `/media`. I have embedded a date & machine id in my filename. Then, ↵

```
Initial image file ROOT filesystem size (MB) [5933]?
```

> NOTE: Accept default ( ↵ )

```
Added space for incremental updates after shrinking (MB) [0]?
```

> NOTE: Accept default ( ↵ )

```
Create /mnt/Passport2TB/img_backups/20210113_Pi4B_imagebackup.img (y/n)? y
```

> NOTE: Enter `y`, then ↵

```
Starting full backup (for incremental backups, run: ./image-backup /mnt/Passport2TB/img_backups/20210113_Pi4B_imagebackup.img)
```

> NOTE: The instructions for making an *incremental* backup are N/A here because you are running `image_backup` on a one-time basis.
> Additional output will show 3 iterations of `resize2fs` to reduce the image file to its smallest possible size, and upon completion, `e2fsck` will be run to verify the integrity of the filesystem.

- **You should now have an image file that is ready to be flashed to your spare SD card.**

#### Verify & inspect the image file

I have used an external drive mounted at `/mnt/Passport2TB` to store my backup image - in a folder named `img_backups`. Your external drive will likely be different than mine. You can verify your external drive is mounted by using the `lsblk --fs` command.

List the contents of `/mnt/Passport2TB/img_backups` to verify the image file is there, and check its size:

```bash
$ ls -l /mnt/Passport2TB/img_backups 
total 28533608

...

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  3921674240 Jan 13 18:48 20210113_Pi4B_imagebackup.img
```

Note that the size of my image file is 3.92GB. Yours will likely be a different size based on which version of the OS you've installed (I use the ***Lite*** version of RPi OS). To provide some context for comparison, let's look at how much space is being used on my RPi 4B:

```bash
$ df -h -t ext4
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root        29G  4.9G   23G  18% /
```

And so, in my case, `image-backup` reduced 4.9GB to a 3.92GB `.img` file - or about a 20% reduction.

Comment: I'm pretty certain the difference between 4.9 and 3.9GB corresponds to 5% of the entire filesystem size. That's the space which is reserved for the `root` user on an EXT file system.

Comment: the tool (https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/download/file.php?id=39167) is 404. [archive.org link](https://web.archive.org/web/20210124225541/https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/download/file.php?id=39167)

Comment: @luckydonald: Thanks, I've edited the link, but you can also find it on [this GitHub site](https://github.com/seamusdemora/RonR-RPi-image-utils)

Comment: Does the `image-backup` script support working on a non-live filesystem (e.g., from an SD card mounted on a desktop computer)? This would ensure write-heavy items like live databases are copied without error.

Comment: @holocronweaver: I don't know - I've never tried anything like that. But you can ask the author (RonR) in the [RPi forum topic](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=332000).

Comment: Link to forum attachment doesn't work anymore.

Comment: @slm: I fixed it (again). I think I'm going to change that link to the general forums page w/ instructions to search...  but I'll do that later. For now, this gets you to "post # 1" of the forum topic which contains the d/l link.

Answer (score 5):

I assume you have a 32 GB SD Card with a productive installation that should be handled save and a spare 16 GB SD Card. You want to transfer the productive installation to the 16 GB SD Card. I would do it manual without special image copying programs. So you are free with partitions, filesystems and its sizes and you have control on each step to be sure that nothing goes wrong.

The idea is to take an uncompressed backup image of the 32 GB SD Card. That is always a good thing to save your productive installation. After copying the installation from it you can compress it for archival storage. We have to use a computer with a Linux operating system. I use one with Debian. I assume you can the SD Cards attach to the computer with a SD Card reader to e.g. device file `/dev/sdb`. For this example I also assume you are using a Raspberry Pi OS.

We will just partition and format the 16 GB SD Card to the sizes you want, mount its partitions, then mount the partitions of the 32 GB image and just copy it files to the 16 GB SD Card. Here are the steps just in short:

Backup card32 to an image and mount its partitions as following:

```
pc ~$ sudo -Es
pc ~# dd if=/dev/sdb of=./card32.img bs=4M conv=fsync

pc ~# losetup --show --find --partscan ./card32.img
/dev/loop0
pc ~# ls /dev/loop0*
/dev/loop0  /dev/loop0p1  /dev/loop0p2
pc ~# fsck -f /dev/loop0p1
pc ~# fsck -f /dev/loop0p2

pc ~# mkdir /mnt/card32
pc ~# mount /dev/loop0p2 /mnt/card32
pc ~# mount /dev/loop0p1 /mnt/card32/boot
```

Attach card16, partition, format, and mount it:

```
pc ~# parted /dev/sdb mktable msdos
pc ~# parted /dev/sdb mkpart primary fat32 2048s 257MiB
pc ~# parted /dev/sdb mkpart primary ext4 257MiB 100%

pc ~# mkfs.vfat -F 32 -n BOOT /dev/sdb1
pc ~# mkfs.ext4 -L rootfs /dev/sdb2

pc ~# mkdir /mnt/card16
pc ~# mount /dev/sdb2 /mnt/card16
pc ~# mkdir /mnt/card16/boot
pc ~# mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/card16/boot
```

Copy the installation from card32 to card16:

```
pc ~# cp -a /mnt/card32/* /mnt/card16/
```

Because the installation is now starting from another SD Card, its PARTUUID has changed and it will not find the root partition. You have to correct this. By about 99 % it is the most critical modification if the new SD Card doesn't boot. If so, have a double check at the partitions name in `/mnt/card16/boot/cmdline.txt` and in `/mnt/card16/etc/fstab`. I don't use the PARTUUID, but instead the device name.

```
pc ~# sed -i 's/root=PARTUUID=[a-z0-9]*-02/root=\/dev\/mmcblk0p2/' /mnt/card16/boot/cmdline.txt
pc ~# sed -i 's/^PARTUUID=[a-z0-9]*-01/\/dev\/mmcblk0p1/' /mnt/card16/etc/fstab
pc ~# sed -i 's/^PARTUUID=[a-z0-9]*-02/\/dev\/mmcblk0p2/' /mnt/card16/etc/fstab

pc ~# umount -R /mnt/card16
pc ~# fsck -f /dev/sdb1
pc ~# fsck -f /dev/sdb2
```

Compress card32.img for the archive if you like:

```
pc ~# dd if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/card32/boot/nullfile bs=4M conv=fsync
pc ~# dd if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/card32/nullfile bs=4M conv=fsync
pc ~# rm /mnt/card32/boot/nullfile
pc ~# rm /mnt/card32/nullfile

pc ~# umount -R /mnt/card32
pc ~# fsck -f /dev/loop0p1
pc ~# fsck -f /dev/loop0p2
pc ~# losetup --detach-all

pc ~# gzip ./card32.img
pc ~# exit
pc ~$
```

Comment: Why do you `mount` a partition before you run `dd` on it?

Comment: @Seamus Where? Have I overseen something?

Comment: I don't use `dd` much, but I *thought* it was common knowledge that the dev/part used as `if` was to be un-mounted before using `dd`. This was due to [the **risk** of data corruption](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/245049/286615). Like many things, risk depends on the situation. I posted the comment because it wasn't clear to me that mounting the drive was necessary to your solution.

Comment: @Seamus In my answer I find 3 lines with `dd`. What line do you mean?

Comment: You have a line that says: `Backup card32 to an image and mount its partitions:`

Comment: But actually, re-reading it now, perhaps you meant that as a summary of the instructions that followed?

Comment: @Seamus Yes, this is meant. I have clarified it in the answer.

Comment: I am curious about something... would you care to participate in an *experiment* with me? I'd like to know how your method compares with the `image-backup` approach answer in terms of: 1) image size; 2) time-to-complete image creation; 3) restoration time. Whaddya' think ??

Comment: couldn't work for me, when I tried to "Attach card16, partition, format, and mount it:" `parted /dev/mmcblk0 mktable msdos` I got this error ` Error: Partition(s) 1 on /dev/mmcblk0 have been written, but we have been unable
to inform the kernel of the change, probably because it/they are in use.  As a
result, the old partition(s) will remain in use.  You should reboot now before
making further changes.
Ignore/Cancel? ignore                                                     
Information: You may need to update /etc/fstab. `

Comment: @mina It has nothing to do with the commands in the answer. It is an dynamic issue of your operating system. Have you rebooted as suggested? You can try to use `sudo partprobe /dev/sdb` without reboot: [How to Reload partition table in Linux without system Reboot?](https://www.2daygeek.com/how-to-reload-partition-table-in-linux-without-system-reboot/).

Comment: @Seamus I think you cannot compare `image-backup` with manual using the operating system. Of course `image-backup` will be faster. Only having a coffee will lose comparison. It is just a complete other method with full control about each single step. This will take more time and steps but you are completely free to create your destination storage as you like. I think `image-backup` cannot modify the first boot partition and if you have a three partitions, you also cannot simply shrink the middle one.

Comment: @Seamus That means you can only shrink the last partition in a simple way and if the middle partition occupies the most of the storage `image-backup` will not help much. But shrinking a default Raspberry Pi OS without special requirements `image-backup` will do a good job, of course. And yes, I like to have full control instead of trusting an "obscure" script, especially in critical operations.

Comment: I understand... I thought the manual steps could perhaps be integrated into a script, but I see your point.

Answer (score 1):

Copying one file system (that obviously doesn’t take up the entire disk) to another, smaller filesystem is quite a common problem, especially in these times where GB’s come in large quantities for no price at all.

I had to look for a bit but remembered a question on the Ubuntu stack exchange: https://askubuntu.com/questions/409204/how-to-clone-to-a-smaller-harddisk

Basically what you proposed is the right way to go but be careful to respect the original layout of your disk if you’ve set it up like this.

-hth

Comment: @mina no problem, I have struggled with this myself recently