# Can't ping or SSH into my pi after update

Tags: ssh, pi-hole

I'm running a headless Pi-Hole. Went ahead with update/upgrade using SSH from my windows machine, which stalled for about an hour. Couldn't connect via SSH anymore. Thinking it had finished, I rebooted with a screen attached. I can connect to the internet, and I can see the pi on my router, just can't connect from my windows machine. Can't ping it and can't SSH into it. They're both on ethernet. I have the correct IP. SSH is enabled. How do I progress from here?

Comment: If you have a [**backup**](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/120124/how-to-copy-sd-card-whithout-copying-the-unallocated-space/120154#120154), **or** if you can afford to lose whatever's on your system now, starting over with a fresh install may be *quicker* than troubleshooting whatever it is that's gone wrong.

Comment: what is the output of `systemctl status sshd.service` - oh, wait, you can't even ping it - can the pi ping the windows machine, or the router?

Comment: How is the RasPi connected using ethernet? Wired or wireless? Execute these commands on it: ip addr` and `ip route`. [Edit](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/127641/edit) your question and add the output to it.

Comment: @JaromandaX He can execute commands on the RasPi. He has a screen attached.

Comment: @Ingo yes, I know ... what makes you think otherwise?

Comment: @JaromandaX maybe I misunderstood your note: "*oh, wait, you can't even ping it*"