# Rescue file from backup

Tags: backup

I made test backup from my Raspberry sd-card to usb-stick using SD Card Copier and now i need to rescue one text file from it.

Earlier when i plugged it in, it said "unrecognized format" or something similar, now it don's show any dialog but lsusb sees it and it don't appear in sidebar.

Comment: When you set up a backup system, always try to restore data from it at least once, until then consider you don't have a backup. More to the point, please clarify how the backup was made (what is "SD Card Copier", a card duplicator of some sort?) and how exactly you tried to restore the file ("i plugged it in" - what did you plug into what, and was there any software involved?).

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, the [`SD Card Copier`](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/filesystem/backup.md) software writes an *image* of your SD card to a USB device - perhaps a USB-SD adapter, or a USB storage device?

> NOTE: *In general, more details make for better questions.*

And so I will *assume* the following:

- You have a working backup on a device that can be plugged into a USB port
- Your RPi remains operational - you can read the USB device with the backup
- You know how to open a terminal window & type commands into it

If this is your situation, you will only need to `mount` your USB device - after it is mounted, you can rummage through it as you wish, and find your text file.

1. Plug the USB device containing the backup into a USB port on your RPi
2. open a terminal & run the command: `lsblk --fs`
3. verify that the USB device appears in the output - it should have two partitions: `/` and `/boot`
4. `mount` the USB device or partition; ref `man mount` or [read this](https://github.com/seamusdemora/PiFormulae/blob/master/ExternalDrives.md)
5. find your text file, and copy it to your active SD card

Any follow-up questions should be made by **editing your question**, and include the output of `lsblk --fs`. This concludes "the answer"; I've added some unsolicited advice in the sequel that may help you in the future.

---

Unsolicited advice:

- Forget `SD Card Copier` - there are better backup solutions. My favorite is [`image-utils`](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/120154/83790)