# Fixing corrupted fstab

Tags: sd-card, boot-issues, fstab, corrupt

My raspberry pi zero ran out of space on its microSD card and somehow corrupted part of the filesystem, as it doesn't boot properly. When I insert the microSD card into another computer, I can look at the `/etc/fstab` file and it looks like this:

```
PARTUUID=d271c287-01  /boot           vfat    defaults          0       2
PARTUUID=d271c287-02  /               ext4    defaults,noatime  0       1
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
```

(Yes, the weird sequence at the bottom is not a mistake - it's what the file looks like). I'm imagining that maybe I can just delete this line and everything will work as normal? I was also thinking that this could maybe due to an odd interpretation of a slightly different charset by my computer, as I've never seen this kind of pattern before.

Comment: Unless you had changed it there are other things missing. Once your FS is corrupt patching files, particularly if disk full, is only going to make things worse. What does `df -h` show. Restore from your backup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd be tempted to manually remove the spurious line from `/etc/fstab`, mount the microSD card on a Linux box (or PC running a live Linux distro), and check the filesystem of each partition with `fsck` before attempting to boot from it again

Answer (score 1):

It may be that your SD card is having issues - they are subject to *wear-out*, and the cheaper ones die younger than (for example) SD cards made by SanDisk.

You should edit `/etc/fstab` to remove the bogus entry, but keep an eye out for other strange behavior. You should also consider making a backup of your system so that you can recover your system if it fails catastrophically. Here's [one way to do that using `image-backup`](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/120154/83790)