# raspberry pi image - decompress and pi shrink in move

Tags: image

I have image of raspberry at 128 GB pendrive ( :'( )

and i don't have free space in this moment at my desktop for 128 GB image.

normally i have coppied with steps

```
sudo dd bs=4M if=/dev/sdc of=pi.img
```

and after

```
sudo pishrink.sh pi.img
```

Is it possible to unzip ( i have zipped before raspi image ) and pi shrink at that same command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a [tutorial on using `pishrink.sh`](https://ostechnix.com/pishrink-make-raspberry-pi-images-smaller/), and the README on the [pishrink GitHub site](https://github.com/Drewsif/PiShrink).

##### As an unsolicited comment:

You shouldn't be making backup (or re-distributable) images of your SD card with `dd`.

Why do I say that? :

- [`dd` will not make a reliable backup of a running system](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/244983/using-dd-to-clone-a-disk-while-mounted-risks)
- `dd` isn't entirely reliable even if you follow all the rules
- there is a much better alternative that **shrinks the image file** and runs on a *live* system: `image-backup`. [This answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/120154/83790) covers some of the details

Answer (score 1):

> possible to unzip ( i have zipped before raspi image ) and pi shrink at that same command

It's pretty clear looking at the github README for pishrink that it's working on the individual partitions in the image by first mounting them.  It can't do that in a pipeline, so the whole image has to exist somewhere first.

Ie., You do need a complete image before you can run pishrink.