# How do I update or reinstall Lxterm on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi-os, newbie

Made some changes and RPI wouldn't load.  Tired fixing but I lost the terminal.  I was able to add XTerm but the font is so small I can't read it.  Would like regular terminal back.  I had to readd Chroimum, that was easy, but can't see how to readd XTerm.

Comment: Any reason you don't just re-flash the OS to your sd card?

Comment: Have you tried Ctrl + right click in Lxterm, then choosing a font size?

Comment: Most of us would just restore from backup. As you haven't said WHAT YOU DID no one can answer.

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, it's not a good idea to *carelessly* make changes to configuration files you're not completely familiar with. And since you don't know what you changed - it's unlikely that we can walk you back to where you started. I started this answer with the idea that I could explain how you could get a copy of the file you modified... but after reading your question again, it seems you may not even recall which files you modified. If that's the case, you are most probably beyond help except for two options:

1. restore from a [backup](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/120154/83790) (which I can *guess* you don't have), or
2. re-flash your SD card with a fresh image & learn from your mistake.