# raspberry pi 3 B v1.2 not booting no led light and heating on the backside

Tags: hardware, power-supply, boot-issues, failure, board-leds

I haven't used the pi for a few month now , it was stored in good condition. so yesterday i flashed the SD card with rasbian bullseye and booted up the pi. every thing was normal except the wifi , i couldnt connect to the wifi it said no wireless interface found. so i unpluged it and left it off till today and when i try to boot it up there is no response now , no leds nor any display output , i lifted up the pi and my had got kinda burned so i unpluged it removed the sd card , the card wasnt hot it was just one electrical component on the backside of the pi thats getting hot(no smoke or smell)[image] when i plug it in ( ive marked its approximate location in the image. so now it wont boot and it wont light up the led ( both green and red ) and when i plug it in it that part of the pi( in the image) get really hot.I was using a 5v 2A adapter , tried powering it from computer usb 3 port too , still the same result. can someone please help with this issue?
and thanks for the replies

Comment: Do you have the original SD card - or did you overwrite it with `bullseye`? Or a [backup image](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/120124/how-to-copy-sd-card-whithout-copying-the-unallocated-space/120154?r=SearchResults&s=7|29.9531#120154) of the original SD card? If so, you should try that before you discard the unit.

Comment: i overwrote it with bullseye and it did run the first day , the problem started the following day and also even without the sd card its heating up and no led is lighting  up.

Comment: I think @joan's answer below is correct. Without proper (expensive) tools, and relevant experience, repairing boards like the RPi is a bit like performing brain surgery with a soup ladle. Also, RPi doesn't publish a complete schematic, making the job x-difficult even if one has the tools & experience.

Comment: seems like that's the only option left . so i was thinking about getting a pi 4 model b 2gb ram version that should be enough for basic usage and entry level computer vision stuff right?

Comment: FWIW - It's what I'd buy. Be advised that recent changes have made installation more tedious due to the politics of computer security. All the images on the RPi website now have default user `pi` removed, no default password, etc, etc - which adds still more configuration work after the installation. Oh - BTW: I respond to ***your*** post & you get a nice notification, **but** if you want to reply to ***my*** comment, I don't get a notification unless you add my handle (@seamus) to the comment.

Comment: I'm new to stack exchange so i didn't know about the notification part so thanks for all the info. Ill get a new one then. @Seamus

Comment: See how well that works?  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Pi is broken.  There is no economical repair.  The most inexpensive and quickest solution is to buy a new Pi.