# if-else to check whether sd card or usb disk.?

Tags: raspberry-pi-os, bash

How can I set this up so that it itself checks if there is an sd or usb, so it makes a backup depending on whether I have an sd card or usb disk attached?

```
dd if=/dev/mmcblk0 of=${BACKUP_PATH}/${HOSTNAME}${ARCHITECTURE}bits-${BACKUP_DATO}.img bs=1MB status=progress
echo "Backup Image from SD-Kort"

dd if=/dev/sda of=${BACKUP_PATH}/${HOSTNAME}${ARCHITECTURE}bits-${BACKUP_DATO}.img bs=1MB status=progress
echo "Backup Image from USB"
```

Comment: I suggest you `man bash` and test to see if the file exists.

Comment: Ugh! Why use `dd` with all of its flaws as a backup solution? Try `image-backup` instead - the ["how to" is in another answer here on SE](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/120154/83790)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If exactly one of `/dev/mmcblk0` and `/dev/sda` exists and shall be saved, you could use something like

```bash
if [ -e /dev/mmcblk0 ]
then
    dd if=/dev/mmcblk0 of=${BACKUP_PATH}/${HOSTNAME}${ARCHITECTURE}bits-${BACKUP_DATO}.img bs=1MB status=progress
    echo "Backup Image from SD-Kort"
else
    dd if=/dev/sda of=${BACKUP_PATH}/${HOSTNAME}${ARCHITECTURE}bits-${BACKUP_DATO}.img bs=1MB status=progress
    echo "Backup Image from USB"
fi
```

or

```
if [ -b /dev/mmcblk0 ]
...
```

`-e` checks the existence of any file system object, `-b` checks for the existence of a block device, `-f` checks for a regular file (which does not match here).

Depending on your needs you could also check what device is mounted as `/`, e.g. by parsing the output of `mount`.

Comment: @Bobo

if [ -f /dev/mmcblk0 ]  
then  
  
i get it to work with :  
  
if [ -b /dev/mmcblk0 ]; then  
  
what is the difference. ?

Comment: @Assassins You are right. It must be `-e` or `-b`, not `-f`; see updated answer.

Comment: @Bobo
Thanks for the answer, you help and time :-)