# Moving RaspberryPi OS to a larger SD card

Tags: boot, sd-card, boot-issues

I am using RaspberryPi OS Lite on my model 3B on a 8Gb SD card, but ran out of space. I tried copying the old SD card using

- dd on the whole SD Card
- dd on both partitions separately
- balenaEtcher (clone drive)
- various other tools for cloning drives

but no matter what I did, when I tried to boot I got a kernel panic because
`/sbin/init exists but couldn't be executed.`
I also tried changing fstab and cmdline.txt replacing the PARTUUID for the root partition with /dev/mmcblk0p2. My old SD still booted but it had no effect on my new SD Card.
I could not find any guide that doesn't use these steps.

Comment: Your question has been [asked](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/120124/how-to-copy-sd-card-whithout-copying-the-unallocated-space), and [answered](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/120154/83790)

Comment: This shell script solved my problem:
https://github.com/billw2/rpi-clone

Comment: It might be a solution that works, but in the end I used a different tool that is easier to use and does exactly what I need. (see answer)

Comment: In that case you should add an answer to the previous existing question, but as per your (deleted) answer here, that should contain meaningful content beyond a pasted link.

Comment: I have a different problem than the author of the previous question. Copying to a larger SD card is different than copying to a smaller SD card and therefore deserves its own thread imo

Comment: The easiest solution is to use the SD Card Copier included in Raspberry Pi OS.