# I've flashed my Pi's SD card to reset it to a earlier state using an img of it but I'm getting this error in etcher all the time

Tags: raspbian, image, restore

This is the error that I’m getting in etcher.

[image]

I've also tried the macOS disk utility tool to restore it but I'm getting errors there too. The error message is German but it says something like the volumes image list couldn’t be retrieved - OSStatus 45.

Also I've tried two images from different dates both were created using disk utility create image.

I’d really like to restore my image because otherwise I’ll have to setup my pi again from ground up.

EDIT:   here is the text version of the error message (used OCR to generate it, so there may be a typo)

```
Invalid typed array length

RangeError: Invalid typed array length
    at Buffer.Uint8Array        (native)

    at FastBuffer               (buffer.js:11:5)
    at createUnsafeBuffer       (buffer.js:37:10)
    at Function.Buffer.alloc    (buffer.js:141:12)

    at ReadStream._read         (/Applications/Etcher.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/udif/lib/readstream.js:128:25)
    at ReadStream._read         (/Applications/Etcher.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/udif/lib/readstream.js:100:19)
    at ReadStream._read         (/Applications/Etcher.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/udif/lib/readstream.js:106:19)
    at ReadStream._read         (/Applications/Etcher.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/udif/lib/readstream.js:118:21)

    at ReadStream.Readable.read (/Applications/Etcher.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:436:10)
    at flow                     (/Applications/Etcher.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:806:34)
    at Pipeline.<anonymous>     (/Applications/Etcher.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:676:7)

    at emitNone                 (events.js:86:13)
    at Pipeline.emit            (events.js:188:7)

    at onwriteDrain             (_stream_writable.js:393:12)
    at afterWrite               (_stream_writable.js:381:5)
    at onwrite                  (_stream_writable.js:374:7)
```

Comment: How exactly did you create the image?

Comment: did you try a different SD card?

Comment: @Dirk "create image" in Disk Utility

Comment: @jsotola yeah I’ve tried a new one as well, also the card was working fine until know.

Comment: I don't know disk utility. Does it create images compatible with Etcher, etc?

Comment: @Dirk i guess it should be compatible it creates .img also I’ve also tried Disk Utility’s own restore function but it didn’t work.

Comment: please remove the image from your question and replace it with the actual text, so that it can be copied and searched on the internet

Comment: You should put additional detail in your question. If you used Disk Utility forget it - for whatever reason it doesn't like Linux images. Next time use `dd`. There is an outside chance you could mount the image on a Linux machine and recover your data.

Comment: @Milliways yeah I'm not going to use Disk Utility for images anymore. `dd` works like it should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the image was created using macOS disk utility and it doesn't like Linux images. If you want to create Linux images use `dd`.

Comment: See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/29085/8697 for a backup script

Comment: @Milliways thanks man this means my `dd` backups are probably worthless. Going to use it the next time.