# Pi 4 - Any good Backup Solutions for Backing Up attached External HDD to another attached external HDD on a Schedule

Tags: pi-4, backup, storage

I am looking at building a Pi 4 NAS using Open Media Vault using some gear I have lying around the house.
I have a external WD USB 3.0 HDD and an external 4TB USB 3.0 HDD
I was planning on setting up the 8TB as the main NAS drive, with some sort of solution to backup the 8TB onto the 4TB on a schedule(Compressed backups)
I don't think I will ever max the 8TB as its mainly for backing up a few devices on the network via True Image 2021
Is there some sort of backup solution available on the PI, that would snapshot the external 8TB to the 4TB ?

Comment: It's a Linux system... so of course there are backup solutions for the RPi. Have you done any research? What was it that confused you? Did you look at `rsync`? Here's a [search that may help you get started](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffnt&q=Linux+backup+solutions&ia=web).

Comment: As already suggestion rsync is great for secure, efficient uni-directional sync of files and folders.

If you want bi-directional there is unison

Or if your happy with tarballs then a combination of ssh and tar will do the job..

Comment: There are a lot of threads about Raspberry and backup. Just search for these keywords ;-)

I use raspiBackup which allows to create a backup either with rsync, tar or dd. See this thread (https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37842/backup-raspberry-pi-automatically-with-incremental-backups/85854#85854) for example for details.