# How to backup sd card running raspibian to disk image?

Tags: raspbian, sd-card, backup

I am running raspibian Jessie on raspberry pi 3,
And I want to backup the entire raspibian OS to a disk image!

Is it possible if I can backup to disk right from within raspibian OS running installed from the sd card on raspberry pi3?

Comment: The most useful script I found for this is listed here by ppumkin: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/5427/can-a-raspberry-pi-be-used-to-create-a-backup-of-itself.  This script creates rolling backups and automatically deletes previous img's.  It can be set to back up your Pi on any external drive.

Answer (score 0):

You could, if you really want an image with lots of rubbish. For a more practical approach see [can-a-raspberry-pi-be-used-to-create-a-backup-of-itself](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/28087/8697)

Comment: Well what are you reffering rubbish too ?

Comment: @Ciastopiekarz Read the link which will describe the stuff you DON'T want.