# rsync exclude-from does not work

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-jessie, backup

I am trying to backup raspbian onto itself following [this stackexchange post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/5427/can-a-raspberry-pi-be-used-to-create-a-backup-of-itself) but it seems the exclude from flag doesnt work,

This is the command I am using

```
sudo  rsync -avH --delete-during --delete-excluded --exclude-from=/home/pi/Desktop/rsync-exclude.txt /  /media/usb0/pi_backup/
```

and this is my rsync-exclude.txt file.

```
/proc/*
/sys/*
/dev/*
/boot/*
/tmp/*
/run/*
/mnt/*
/data/*
/media/*

.Trashes
._.Trashes
.fseventsd
.Spotlight-V100
.DS_Store
.cache
.AppleDesktop
.AppleDB
Network Trash Folder
Temporary Items
lost+found

.bash_history
/etc/fake-hwclock.data
/home/pi/pydio-core-6.2.2.tar.gz
/var/lib/rpimonitor/stat/
/home/pi/.cache/
/media/usb0/
/home/pi/.kodi/addons/
/home/pi/Library/Application Support/Plex Media Server/
```

[image]

and this is the command I am using now that is resulting what above you can see

```
shopt -s dotglob; sudo  rsync -auvoltH --devices --delete-during -E --stats --progress --exclude "/home/pi/pi_backup2/home/kodi/.kodi/userdata/Thumbnails/" --exclude "/media/" --exclude "/home/pi/.cache/" --exclude "/home/pi/Library/Application Support/Plex Media Server/" --exclude "/home/kodi/.kodi/addons/" --log-file=/home/pi/Desktop/backup.log --delete-excluded --exclude-from "/home/pi/Desktop/rsync-exclude.txt" /  /media/usb0/pi_backup/
```

Comment: In what sense doesn't it work?  As in, at all?  All that stuff just gets copied?

Comment: Yes , it gets copied however I passed individual path to --exclude flag while passing command and that works but not the paths from file

Comment: Dunno what to say.  I just tried replicating this -- normally I don't have blank lines or paths with spaces, but all that didn't make any difference.  It worked as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the command below.

```
sudo  rsync -avH --delete-during --delete-excluded --exclude-from '/home/pi/Desktop/rsync-exclude.txt' / /media/usb0/pi_backup/
```

> The exclude from should be used as
>   --exclude-from '/home/backup/exclude.txt' instead of --exclude-from-/home/backup/exclude.txt

Change your path to relative paths. I think that's where the problem is.

The tricky thing with rsync is that you need to use a relative path when you are trying to exclude things, because when it tries to match the exclusions it won’t use the first part of the path for the match…

```
proc/*
sys/*
dev/*
boot/*
tmp/*
run/*
mnt/*
data/*
media/*
```

Comment: `--exclude-from=foobar.txt` should be fine as long as the file path doesn't include spaces.

Comment: File path doesn't includes spaces, however a hyphen in file name. I tried as per answer the but proc, sys and all folder mentioned by @goldilocks are getting created

Comment: If you use `/proc/*` the `proc` *folder* should be created, just nothing in it will be copied, and the destination side contents will be deleted.  I.e., it should be empty afterward.