# Resizing Raspberry Pi Image

Tags: raspbian, image, backup

I am trying to make a backup of my raspian image, so I can distribute it to more Raspberrys in the future. I used `dd` for that, but as my sd card is larger then the image, I ended up with a 16 Gb file instead of 4.5.

I found several instructions on how to shrink this, like http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-BackUp-and-Shrink-Your-Raspberry-Pi-Image/ or the `pishrink.sh` script. But these instructions all produce images which are substantially larger than needed (~6.5 Gb). This seems to be the case because `resize2fs` is miscalculating the minimum size.

How can I produce an image which has the optimal size?

Comment: So is the minimum size GParted calculated 6.4GiB, and could you add a screenshot of GParted please?

Comment: No. Gparted calculated 4.5 but if I set it to 4.5 and try to apply it in gparted, gparted stops with an error and the error message says, that this is higher than the minimum size reported by resize2fs

Comment: If you want to produce an optimal image you need to approach this from a different perspective. Think months of effort; you can find details of how Raspbian images are made if you want to follow this approach. Shrinking a working image will never approach this, because this contains a lot of cruft, which will be regenerated. The simplest approach which stands a chance of success is to generate an image file (of the appropriate size) and use `rsync` to copy the relevant parts of the working image.

Comment: This can be automated, but AFAIK there is no existing script to do this. [can-a-raspberry-pi-be-used-to-create-a-backup-of-itself](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/28087/8697)
should provide a starting point

Comment: This is one reason `dd` is a lousy backup tool.  That's not its intended purpose.