# Rsync freezing when trying to backup

Tags: raspbian, backup, rsync

I have been looking at other threads. Some have said the problem is a permission issue, and some have said it hasn't been solved. I am using rsync to backup to a USB drive. When I insert the usb drive, I can find it in /media/pi/USBNAME. Here is the command I'm using.

```
sudo rsync -avH --delete-during --delete-excluded --exclude-from=/home/pi/Documents/backup/rsync-exclude.txt / /media/pi/*/
```

It works fine for a while, but then it will randomly stop copying the files to the USB drive. If I re-run the command, it will stop at a different file.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Who knows what `/media/pi/*/` will actually do.

You should NOT use wildcards with `rsync` and generally you would NOT use a trailing `/` on the target. (This depends on exactly what you are trying to achieve `rsync` is rather particular about directory paths.)

See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/28087/8697 for a script I use.

NOTE I **ALWAYS** check that the target drive is mounted in RW mode. Otherwise `rsync` will still try to copy somewhere, and may copy to your SD Card (until full).

I mount my backup drive with `sudo mount /mnt/PiData`
**NOTE** `/mnt/PiData` must already exist

This requires an entry in `/etc/fstab` such as the following:-

```
UUID=94dc6686-0eda-41ba-87f7-494d7e37f913       /mnt/PiData     ext4    defaults,noatime,noauto  0     0
```

You can use the following to find the UUID of your partition:-

`sudo blkid  /dev/sda`

Comment: Would you mind helping me configure this script to mine settings. Not very familiar with bash. So when I plug in the USB (it's called Test) it is located in /media/pi/Test/. How can check if this is RW along as check that this path is there.

Comment: @Test4444 if you post a script you will get help - you need to add more information. The first thing I would do is NOT use /media and automatic mounting. Start by adapting my script. Preferably exit the GUI and run on command line.

Comment: @Test4444 I am not at a computer - how is disk formatted?

Comment: I formated with sudo mkfs.vfat /dev/sda. How do I not use /media for automatic mounting. I am not using any GUI, I can only connect to the pi through ssh.

Comment: @Test4444 As per my linked Answer "I backup to an **ext4** partition on a HDD mounted on the Pi" You cannot backup to a FAT partition. **DO NOT post detail into comments - EDIT your question.** If you are not using GUI (which automounts removable media) - how do you mount?

Comment: I don't mount at all, I plug it in, and I can start reading & writing to /media/pi/Test/