# Full backup of server

Tags: pi-2, linux, backup

I am building a web server od Raspberry Pi 3. The system and the data will be on microSD card and I am curious if there's any way to automaticaly backup the whole card with data? I mean - if anything happens to the card, i simply download the backup file, restore it to new microSD card and put it to the raspberry Pi without doing configuration or instalation of new web server.

I d'like to use Synology NAS as a backup server.

Comment: Hardly a duplicate - while there are a number of answers NONE will "restore it to new microSD card and put it to the raspberry Pi without doing configuration or instalation (sic)"

Answer (score 0):

rsync is always a good candidate for backups, especially if you want to automate them, because it can do incremental backups.

Have a look at this answer [Can a Raspberry Pi be used to create a backup of itself?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/5492/97392).
If you plan on keeping unarchived backups on another machine also check my answer on a related question [Restore backup failed (using rsync)](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/92957/97392)

Answer (score 0):

Raspbian has a number of backup utilities - I have used `backintime-gnome` to back up to a HDD, and I am sure this would work to a server.

`rsync` can be used to backup files, but to fully restore requires a formatted/partitioned SD Card and does not manage partitioning.

Both of the above perform incremental backups.

There are numerous backup utilities in the repository you can install.

`dd` can be used to backup a full image to a file - but each time makes a new full backup.
This can be used to image to a server (or any other storage device) and will restore to an identical (or larger) SD Card.

Answer (score 0):

That's why I wrote a script to backup my Raspberries. Initially dd was used, then tar and finally rsync. The script is called [raspiBackup](https://www.linux-tips-and-tricks.de/en/backup/) and [OpenSource](https://github.com/framps/raspiBackup). Just give it a try.