# Failed to start Load Kernel Modules after rsync restore

Tags: boot-issues, raspbian-buster, backup, pi-1, rsync

After restoring the whole raspbian system using rsync, I get following errors during boot.

```
systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service: Main process exited, code=exited, sta...
systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service: Failed with result ´exit-code´.
systemd[1]: Failed to start Load Kernel Modules.
```

After this also `netfilter-persistent.service` and `hostapd.service` fail to start.

What got corrupted here and how can I correct this?

Following are the steps how I do the backup.

I followed the answer to [Can a Raspberry Pi be used to create a backup of itself?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/5427/can-a-raspberry-pi-be-used-to-create-a-backup-of-itself/) backup my running raspbian system. Instead of a USB drive, I use a rsync server for backup. Here is my setup and the commands I use.

Configuration of my rsync server:

```
$ cat /etc/rsyncd.conf
#global (globale einstellung)
log file = /var/log/rsync.log
pid file = /var/run/rsyncd.pid
lock file = /var/run/rsync.lock
timeout = 300

[rpi]
path = /mnt/sdb1/backups/rpi
comment = backup
max connections = 1
hosts allow = 192.168.0.2
hosts deny = *
use chroot = yes
list = true
uid = root
gid = root
read only = false
auth users = user
secrets file = /etc/rsyncd.secrets
```

On my Raspberry I execute following command to start the backup:

```
sudo rsync -aHv --numeric-ids --delete --exclude-from=/home/user/rsync-exclude.txt --password-file=/home/user/rsync-pass / rsync://user@192.168.0.1/rpi/rsync_backup/
```

Content of `rsync-exclude.txt`

```
$ cat rsync-exclude.txt
/proc/*
/sys/*
/dev/*
/boot/*
/tmp/*
/run/*
/mnt/*
/media/*
/var/swap
/var/log/*
```

To restore the content on the sdcard, I insert the Raspberrie's sdcard in the rsync server and mount the 2nd partition on this sdcard as `/mnt/sdcard`. Afterwards I execute following command to start the restore.

```
sudo rsync -av --numeric-ids --delete-during /mnt/sdb1/backups/rpi/rsync_backup/ /mnt/sdcard/
```

When booting from this sdcard, I get the above described errors.

**Update:**
I now updated my procedure so that also the boot partition is backed up and restored.

Please see the following snippets for error investigation.

```
$ uname -r
4.19.97+

$ ls -l /lib/modules
total 24
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Feb 20  2019 4.14.79+
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Mar  8 11:53 4.14.98+
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Apr 17 19:50 4.19.97+
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Apr 17 19:50 4.19.97-v7+
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Apr 17 19:50 4.19.97-v7l+
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Apr 17 19:50 4.19.97-v8+
```

Comment: Edit in the output from `uname -r` and `ls -l /lib/modules`.  I'm guessing in between when the backup was made and used, the kernel was updated.  This goes into the first partition and would replace the previous one.  At the same time, a corresponding `/lib/modules/x.x.x` was created (where 'x.x.x' is a kernel version), but then in doing your update that directory was deleted (the `uname` and `ls` information will confirm or disprove this). The modules are matched exactly to the kernel version; it can't use the old ones.

Comment: @goldilocks: please see the update of my initial post for output of `uname` and `ls`.

Comment: Okay, so the right directory is there.  Does `lsmod` (list loaded modules) list anything? If not, try `sudo modprobe -v xt_conntrack` (is possibly required by `netfilter-persistent`).

Comment: @goldilocks: Your last hin already helpt me. The crucial point was to backup and restore the boot partition also. After this, my raspberry works as usual again. I did not really test it yesterday because I still saw that `systemd-modules-load.service` failed to start. But `netfilter-persistent.service` started correctly. `systemd-modules-load.service` failed because I had some remaining issues from some day when I tested `lirc`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error described in my question/issue above was caused by issues of kernel files located in the boot partition. Originally I only backed up the files on the "os" partition of the Raspberry. So if you update the kernel or parts of the kernel and restore the files on the "os" partition, the kernel files on the "os" partition are not compatible with the files on the boot partition (or `/boot` folder). The files on the "os" partition are from a newer kernel version than on the boot partition (or vice versa).

So the solution is: Do not only backup the files from "os" partition. Include also the files from the boot partition (mounted as `/boot`) in your backup.

So here is the necessary configuration and the necessary steps:

Configuration of my rsync server:

```
$ cat /etc/rsyncd.conf
#global (globale einstellung)
log file = /var/log/rsync.log
pid file = /var/run/rsyncd.pid
lock file = /var/run/rsync.lock
timeout = 300

[rpi]
path = /mnt/sdb1/backups/rpi
comment = backup
max connections = 1
hosts allow = 192.168.0.2
hosts deny = *
use chroot = yes
list = true
uid = root
gid = root
read only = false
auth users = user
secrets file = /etc/rsyncd.secrets
```

On my Raspberry I execute following command to start the backup:

```
sudo rsync -aHv --numeric-ids --delete --exclude-from=/home/user/rsync-exclude.txt --password-file=/home/user/rsync-pass / rsync://user@192.168.0.1/rpi/rsync_backup/
sudo rsync -aHv --numeric-ids --delete --password-file=/home/user/rsync-pass /boot/ rsync://user@192.168.0.1/rpi/rsync_backup_boot/
```

Content of `rsync-exclude.txt`

```
$ cat rsync-exclude.txt
/proc/*
/sys/*
/dev/*
/boot/*
/tmp/*
/run/*
/mnt/*
/media/*
/var/swap
/var/log/*
```

To restore the content on the sdcard, I insert the Raspberrie's sdcard in the rsync server and mount the boot partition as `/mnt/rpi_boot`. The 2nd partition ("os" partition) on this sdcard is mounted as `/mnt/rpi`. Afterwards I execute following command to start the restore.

```
sudo rsync -av --numeric-ids --delete-during /mnt/sdb1/backups/rpi/rsync_backup/ /mnt/rpi/
sudo rsync -av --numeric-ids --delete-during /mnt/sdb1/backups/rpi/rsync_backup_boot/ /mnt/rpi_boot/
```

Comment: What do you mean? `/boot/*` is in my `rsync-exclude`. Please see answer above.

Comment: Sorry! Missed that.