# Is there a way to flash and make changes in micro sd card through pc which was flashed on raspberry pi

Tags: boot, boot-issues

I installed ubuntu 22.04 on micro sd card and flashed it on raspberry pi zero.

I installed in headless mode. So I don't have monitor and other peripherals. I was able to connect with it through ssh. But now wifi password is changed, so I am not able to connect with it.

Is there a way to flash that micro sd card on my pc, to change wifi password?

Comment: find a functional scrap router and use it to connect to the RPi, then update the password

Comment: You can edit the SD Card on any Linux computer

Comment: [This answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/109364/83790) may help you - see the *Restoration* part of the answer.