# Raspberry Pi kernel image installation on new SD Card (no pre installed Raspbian or NOOBS in it - it's free with no partions)

Tags: sd-card, kernel, filesystem, cross-compilation

I have been working on kernel compilation of Raspberry Pi on Ubuntu using a cross compiler. I have compiled the kernel, and I got the image file generated (https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/kernel/building.md). The website I mentioned only tells how to install our compiled kernel on pre-installed [NOOBS](https://github.com/raspberrypi/noobs) or Raspbian sdcard.

I have done Raspbian installation on an SD card and have seen partions where boot partions (FAT32) contains elf, kernel image, config.txt, etc. and the other partition (ext4) contains some folders.

I tried partitioning my new SD card in to FAT32 (bootable) and ext4 and copied the `start.elf` kernel image, bootcode, dtb, etc. into the boot folder and followed the make of modules and modules_install step for my second partion, but after installing the folder alignment doesn't look like the preinstalled Raspbian ext4 folder.

I know there is some file system doing that. How do I build an OS and file system on a new SD card?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you would want to make your own OS.

There is far more to making an OS than constructing a kernel.

Assuming you want your own kernel, why not follow the procedure you referenced on top of a standard install.

If you really want to, the following describes how to structure the partitions (and the 8K offset of the 1st sector is critical).

```
http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/29947/reverse-the-expand-root-fs/29952#29952
```