# is it possible to configure noobs via ssh?

Tags: ssh

It's a while i dealed the last time with a raspberry. Here my questions:

Is it possible to configure a raspberry with noobs via ssh?

Which is the default password to noobs?

Thanks a lot in advance for any pointer.

Comment: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/59450/enable-ssh-in-noobs-before-install       That was just a simple google search to find this.....

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! Conclusion, it is not ... (?)