# RaspberryPi 4 access ssh on first time setup without changing boot data

Tags: pi-4, ssh, ethernet, noobs, setup

I recently got RPi 4 kit and I want to connect to its terminal interface using Ethernet cable from my laptop. I dont have any SD card reader on my laptop so I cannot change data on microSD. That microSD card has installed NOOBS by default. How can I connect to RPi terminal without buying any additional hardware and by using only my laptop and Ethernet cable? Thanks.

I'm able to ping "raspberrypi.local" from cmd.

PS: My WiFi is on "public" network so I dont have access to router or anything if that helps.
Thanks.

Comment: "That microSD card has installed NOOBS"  [NOOBS](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/92069/8697) is OBSOLETE and hasn't been updated in YEARS. I am surprised it boots on a Pi4, but would be way out of date. You should object to whoever conned you into buying it. Do yourself a favour and spend $5 on a SD Card reader.

Comment: If you REALLY want to persist with it you NEED a keyboard & monitor.

Comment: I would recommend a USB mouse as well

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Enable SSH in NOOBS before install](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/59450/enable-ssh-in-noobs-before-install)

Answer (score 0):

You can't! SSH can be enabled if you add a file ssh to the boot folder on the SD card before first boot.

Comment: This DOES NOT work on NOOBS

Comment: OK, then it is a duplicate of https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/59450/enable-ssh-in-noobs-before-install