# starting with raspberry 3 (headless)

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, ssh

I have bought a Pi and am a little clueless what to do in order to start working on it. I bought a starter kit with a sd-card (NOOBS Software on it). Shouldn't it be possible, to put the micro-sd in the Pi, plug in the power-cable and access the Pi via ssh (headless)?

I read, that ssh must be actived in some cases before. But when I plug in the sd-card in my PC I see something like this:

I created an empty file "ssh" (no file extensions) to activate ssh, as can be seen.

However, whenever I type `ssh pi@192.168.x.x`, on my Ubuntu Terminal on the Home PC, I get `Permission denied, please try again.` The password I type is *raspberry*.

Shouldn't everything be set correctly already?

The starter kit is from: `https://www.amazon.de/Raspberry-Pi-3-Wert-Starter-Kit/dp/B01M3VQBK1/ref=sr_1_sc_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1514482690&sr=8-2-spell`

I think, I have to change the SD-card somehow.. But I am not sure how..

My home PC has Ubuntu 16.04.

Thanks everyone!

---

EDIT:

Hello again!

Thank you all for your help. I briefly want to share, what I have done so far.

I have installed Raspbian as OS on the sd-card now. It worked. 
Then I have added an empty ssh file (no file extension) in order to enable ssh service on the Pi. 
Then I created a `wpa_supplicant.conf` file, which contains my wifi information. It lookes like this:

`ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=AU
network={
    ssid="Your WiFi SSID"
    psk="Your WiFi password"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}`

Both, `ssh` file and `wpa_supplicant.conf` file are in the boot partition of the sd-card now.

However, ssh connection is still not possible... I still get the `permission denied` message.

I made some changes in the `config.txt` and the `cmdline.txt` file as suggested in this tutorial: *https://www.mickmake.com/archives/2777*. But it still doesn't work.

I also set a rule in the Ubuntu firewall to allow ssh: `sudo ufw allow 22/tcp`. That didn't help either.

Another thing, that confuses me is, that the ssh file and the wpa_supplicant.conf seem to have dissapeared after I take the sd-card out of my laptop.

I also tried to check the default password on `/etc/passwd`, however, I can't find it in there:

`root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
daemon:x:1:1:daemon:/usr/sbin:/usr/sbin/nologin
bin:x:2:2:bin:/bin:/usr/sbin/nologin
sys:x:3:3:sys:/dev:/usr/sbin/nologin
sync:x:4:65534:sync:/bin:/bin/sync
games:x:5:60:games:/usr/games:/usr/sbin/nologin
man:x:6:12:man:/var/cache/man:/usr/sbin/nologin
lp:x:7:7:lp:/var/spool/lpd:/usr/sbin/nologin
mail:x:8:8:mail:/var/mail:/usr/sbin/nologin
news:x:9:9:news:/var/spool/news:/usr/sbin/nologin
uucp:x:10:10:uucp:/var/spool/uucp:/usr/sbin/nologin
proxy:x:13:13:proxy:/bin:/usr/sbin/nologin
www-data:x:33:33:www-data:/var/www:/usr/sbin/nologin
backup:x:34:34:backup:/var/backups:/usr/sbin/nologin
list:x:38:38:Mailing List Manager:/var/list:/usr/sbin/nologin
irc:x:39:39:ircd:/var/run/ircd:/usr/sbin/nologin
gnats:x:41:41:Gnats Bug-Reporting System (admin):/var/lib/gnats:/usr/sbin/nologin
nobody:x:65534:65534:nobody:/nonexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin
systemd-timesync:x:100:103:systemd Time Synchronization,,,:/run/systemd:/bin/false
systemd-network:x:101:104:systemd Network Management,,,:/run/systemd/netif:/bin/false
systemd-resolve:x:102:105:systemd Resolver,,,:/run/systemd/resolve:/bin/false
systemd-bus-proxy:x:103:106:systemd Bus Proxy,,,:/run/systemd:/bin/false
pi:x:1000:1000:,,,:/home/pi:/bin/bash
messagebus:x:104:109::/var/run/dbus:/bin/false
avahi:x:105:110:Avahi mDNS daemon,,,:/var/run/avahi-daemon:/bin/false
ntp:x:106:111::/home/ntp:/bin/false
sshd:x:107:65534::/var/run/sshd:/usr/sbin/nologin
statd:x:108:65534::/var/lib/nfs:/bin/false
lightdm:x:109:114:Light Display Manager:/var/lib/lightdm:/bin/false
pulse:x:110:116:PulseAudio daemon,,,:/var/run/pulse:/bin/false
rtkit:x:111:118:RealtimeKit,,,:/proc:/bin/false`

I currently have no ideas, what the problem could be.

Comment: Related: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/59450/19949 and https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/59429/19949

Comment: Sidenote: could you please reformat that figure to contain less *nothingness*?

Answer (score 1):

[NOOBS](https://www.raspberrypi.org/help/noobs-setup/2/) is an operating system install manager, not an operating system.  If you haven't selected an operating system to install via NOOBS, you cannot use SSH to remotely connect to your raspberry pi.

If you intend to use Raspbian, I recommend [flashing](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/) Raspbian directly to an SD card.

Next, you will still need to [add the ssh file](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/58478/ssh-not-working-with-fresh-install) to the SD card once flashed in order to enable SSH on Raspbian.

Comment: Hello and welcome! This answer https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/67353/19949 claims different. Did you test it or have some references?

Comment: @Ghanima That link states "run by noobs at **end** of rasbian install" - you still need a keyboard for initial setup.

Comment: @Milliways fair enough, but that requires prior knowledge of how noobs works, from the answer alone one cannot derive this. As always we seem to come to the conclusion that noobs in fact overcomplicates things and people would be better of using just Raspbian.

Answer (score 0):

You **NEED** a keyboard and screen to setup NOOBS. See https://www.raspberrypi.org/learning/software-guide/

Unless you intend to run multiple OS from the card, just download Raspbian.

Answer (score 0):

U can install the latest ArchLinuxARM. The installation can be done from an host PC with SD Card Reader.

After the installation u will be able to connect remotely via SSH

Regards