# File Manager and fdisk report different partition sizes

Tags: partition

*I'm new to Raspberry Pi.*

The 8 GB SD card that came with my RPi 3 type B showed only 500 MB free, probably due to the pre-installed Mathematica (thanks WRI!).
So I moved the card image to a 32 GB SD card using Win32 Disk Imager. I decided to use `fdisk` to expand the root partition to the card's extents:

```
$ sudo fdisk /dev/mmcblk0
```

where I removed the root partition, re-created it with the same start sector, but using the default end sector, which is the last sector on the card. Concluded with `w` to save everything. When after rebooting I went to `fdisk` again it now shows a 29.7 GB partition, which seems correct, but File Manager PCManFM reports:

> Free space: 541 MiB (Total: 7.2 GiB)

Did I miss anything? How can I fix the numbers File Manager is reporting (assuming they are wrong)?

Comment: What does `sudo fdisk -l /dev/mmcblk0` show now?

Comment: Like I said it shows the root partition to be 29.7 GB.

Comment: I did not ask what you said, I asked you to edit the question and include the result. Anyway you got it solved now.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I forgot to let the partition manager pass the changes to the file manager.

```
sudo resize2fs /dev/mmcblk0p2
```

and everything is peachy.

Comment: This finishes the process because it is the last step, but it is **not** because you "forgot to let the partition manager pass the changes to the file manager"!  [You should read this](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/51100/5538).  The reason you had the problem is because of the difference between *a partition* and *a filesystem*.  One usually contains the other but they are not the same thing.  So you had a  ~30 GB *partition* with an 8 GB *filesystem* in it (hence `resize2fs` -- the "fs" is for *filesystem*; this is **not** a "partition manager" ...see also `man resize2fs`).

Comment: @goldilocks - Well, the file system gets updated from the partition system, doesn't it? Anyway, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: The point is **no** the filesystem *does not get updated from the partition system* (BTW calling the last one a "system" may add to the confusion; it's true in the sense that you can all anything a system -- "Let's get into the car system" -- but who does that?).  There are tools that will do both things at once for you (e.g., presumably most fancy Windows/OSX based things), which is probably why people conflate the two.