# Using a Raspberry Pi to write an image to an SD Card

Tags: hardware, sd-card

Hie

I have an SD card Module and can access connect two SD cards to my raspberry pi, however i would like to be write an image in the other card connected to the SD Card Module

Comment: Hello, what commands have you already tried and did you get any errors? Add this information to your question. Your question is a little open ended at the moment as its not clear if you are just asking *how* to write an image to an SD card or that you *tried* but are having problems.

Comment: I want to write an image to an SD Card. The image files are stored on a raspberry pi and i want to write them to the SD card connected to a raspberry Pi through an SD card module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to identify *the device* node representing the card. Understanding [the difference between a block device, a device partition, and a filesystem](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/51100/5538) is probably a good thing at this point.  The device node is not a mount point.  If there are no other storage devices attached to the Pi, it will probably be `/dev/sda`.  Note for emphasis in case you did not read that link: *not* `/dev/sda1`.

Then if the image is `raspberrypi.img`:

```
sudo dd if=raspberrypi.img of=/dev/sda bs=4M status=progress
```

That will take a few minutes.

Comment: I understand the device node representing the card is a block device. Now i want to know is if it is possible to have a program like win32 disk imager runninh on the raspberry pi so i can use it to write new images to the SD card connected via an SD Card Module

Comment: Yes. This is the most bulletproof method; if you want a GUI instead it is only going to get more complicated, not less.

Comment: [One user on the forums](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=62&t=255205&start=25#p1564958) recently managed to get balenaEtcher to run on a Pi . I prefer using it than `dd` because Etcher verifies after flashing.

Comment: Looks "more complicated" to me. I'd presume some frontend to gparted could do this too, although I have never tried.  If you want to validate `cmp raspberrypi.img /dev/sda` should do it  -- not sure if it will "fail" at the end of the image if reading `/dev/sda` does not end with EOF, but probably not and if so that is not a real problem: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/29921/25985