# Preconfigure Raspbian with packages installed

Tags: raspbian

I found several guides to adjust the Wifi-Passwords prior to the first boot but I need to install certain packages (with apt-get) on the first boot (or even package them into the image) and some custom software that was developed by us. How would I do that?

The reason for this is that I‘m working on a project where we want to eventually provide a final Raspbian image that my school can take, flash to their SD cards and insert them into their Pis. We are developing a presentation application that can be used from your phone/tablet and should not need any further installation.

Comment: I understand that this is for a school project and probably not worth the time or effort so I won't add an answer, but the long term solution here is probably using something like Yocto instead of Raspian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this the same way `raspi-config` works, by running a boot service that disables itself after being run once.

If shell scripting isn't your thing, you may want to look into configuration tools such as [puppet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puppet_(software)) or [chef](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chef_(software)).

> we want to eventually provide a final Raspbian image that my school can take

This sounds like you instead want want to create a ready made image.  If so, you can simply start with a fresh image on a running pi, install what you want, and then create a new image from the SD card.  E.g., using another linux machine:

```
dd if=/dev/sdb of=my.img bs=4M count=???
```

Since this is copying from an entire device (and not just a partition), you will have to figure out how much to copy (`count=???`) -- you probably do not want an image the size of the card itself.  A complication here is that current versions of Raspbian enlarge themselves automatically when first run.  You thus may need to:

[Reverse the expand root FS](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/29947/5538)

Or you could do a little digging and disable the auto-expansion on the card before using it.  You can also do this with the image itself:

[How can I mount a Raspberry Pi Linux distro image?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/13137/5538)

The above Q&A may help you understand the nature of multi-partition device images, as used with the Pi, if you do not already.  *Once this is clear to you creating a customized image should be straightforward.*

Comment: I'm sorry for not getting back to you earlier. I used this and started learning about raspi-config. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you're satisfied with installing packages automatically on first boot rather than actually baking the packages into the image, you might like to consider [PiBakery](http://www.pibakery.org/about.html). You can configure actions to run at various times (such as 'On first boot, install [X]'), and a bootable image will be produced from this.

The GUI is rather like Scratch, so it may be more accessible and straightforward than creating a custom image manually (although it is, of course, much less flexible).

You can also configure a default Wi-Fi setup, and there are various other blocks available for different tasks. PiBakery can be run on Windows or Mac (but curiously, not Linux!) and does support Raspbian Stretch.