# Reverse the expand root FS on Raspbian Stretch fails

Tags: raspbian-stretch

Referring to @goldilocks [Reverse the expand root FS](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/29947/reverse-the-expand-root-fs/77687#77687)

I'm using the latest Rasbian Stretch and have sent an rsync backup to my NAS which is mounted via an NFS mount. Now I am attempting @goldilocks guide to create a new blank image file on the NAS to send the rsync backup into. There are 2 problems....

```
"dd if=/dev/zero of=test.img bs=4096 count=1000" creates a 4M file not 40M
```

Making the file 40M and continuing up to the losetup line where I hit an error that I cannot bypass.

```
losetup -o 4194304 /dev/loop1 test.img"
```

Changing the file.img permissions to 777 doesn't help this error

```
losetup: /dev/loop1: failed to set up loop device: Permission denied
```

Is the because Rasbian Stretch is different, or is just me?

Comment: Thanks for catching that 4/40 MB thing (now corrected). *"Changing the file.img permissions to 777 doesn't help this error"* -> Did you try as root or via `sudo`?  A different loop device (`ls /dev` should show half a dozen or so)?  `sudo losetup -D` in case a prior attempt did something odd?

Comment: Yes, ls /dev shows loop0 to loop7 along with loop-control. But attempt to cleanup didn't help.  Running " sudo losetup -o 4194304 /dev/loop1 test.img"
 completes without error...

Comment: @goldilocks Subsequent commands to mkfs.vfat and losetup -D also require a sudo to complete.  mkdir works as listed, but mount needs sudo to work.  The first mount completes successfully, but the second one complains "/test.img: overlapping loop device exists"

Comment: Yes -- near the beginning of the original post I wrote *"Some of these commands need to be run root so I recommend you just `su root`."*  If you search downward for "overlapping loop" you will find a note about that and a link (not all versions of mount have this issue).  The link is another long answer so you may again want to search downward for "overlapping loop".

Answer (score 0):

> Changing the file.img permissions to 777 doesn't help this error

You do need read-write permission on the image file, but the error here is probably about the permissions on the device node in `/dev`; `stat /dev/loop1` will likely show it as 660, uid root, gid disk.

You could change the permissions or ownership on that, but it would probably be better to use `sudo`, or if that doesn't work, `su root` and do it (if you don't have a root password set you'll have to `sudo passwd root` first).

Note the file nodes in `/dev` are virtual and are created by the kernel, so if you do modify anything the changes will not persist across boot.

Comment: Yes, sudo works fine and su root also works.  Regarding the failure to "mount -o offset=14680064 -t ext4 test.img two" I cannot find anything wrong in your offsets.  Looks good to me.  Puzzled.....  
Device     Boot Start   End Sectors  Size Id Type
test.img1        8192 28671   20480   10M  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
test.img2       28672 79999   51328 25.1M 83 Linux

Comment: Some versions of mount (e.g., the one used by Debian/Raspbian) need you to also specify a size for a partition inside an image file if it does not use the whole file; see my comment on the question here or the bit about "overlapping loop" in the original Q&A.

Comment: So the only other to do it is " mount -o offset=14680064,sizelimit=26279936 -t ext4 test.img two" since we have 51328*512 for size.  This still complains that overlapping loop device exists.  Maybe I am not understanding your helpful pointers?

Comment: In this folder, along with the test.img file, we have 2 empty folders, one called one, and one called two.  Neither one has any lost+found directory in it.

Comment: If it successfully mounted as `ext4` (you can check by running `mount | grep   test.img`; there should be something like `test.img on /some/path/two type ext4`) then it should be fine.   Mkfs should have created that folder, it is used by filesystem repair tools like `e2fsck` to put bits of files found when resolving some corruption.  So if in the end it isn't there create it, uid root gid root permissions 700.

Comment: /test1# mount | grep test.img
/mnt/robinDisk1/downloads/test1/test.img on /mnt/robinDisk1/downloads/test1/one type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)

Comment: Don't I need a successful mount of two first?  You can tell my linux skills are in great need.  Thanks for your patience.

Comment: My goal here is to have an online pi that will be sitting here at home while I am halfway around the world for the 6 months.  I need to have it stay backed up while I am gone so once a week when the NAS is up, the PI will back itself up to the NAS.  Finally now I need to be able to restore the backup to a fresh SD card just in case it fubars....

Comment: I meant the second (ext4) partition; the little first one is vfat.  So it looks like it did not mount, which might explain why you did not find `lost+found`.  If you use `-v` with `mount`, it is more verbose (although it should indicate failure no matter what).  If `mkfs.ext4` runs correctly, it takes maybe 30-60 seconds and reports stuff as it is working.  All I can say is go through it again.  It is the kind of thing that is tedious and frustrating until you get the in and out of it.