# How to make an image file from scratch

Tags: boot, image, operating-systems, partition

I want to make my own image file for a Raspberry Pi so I can copy any usable operating system to it and boot it. This way I'm also able to size down partitions or use other partition sizes.

Is it possible to create a new but empty image file and copy an operating system from other sources to it, for example from another SD Card, an available image or a tar archive?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible to create an empty image for a Raspberry Pi. Then you can copy an operating system with a boot and root partition to it and boot. To fill the empty image you can use any usable file copy method, e.g. from a **tar** archive, or **rsync**, or just **cp**. This way you are completely free to shrink or expand storage, or use other partition sizes than given by the original images. You can do all of it on a linux laptop, no need to use a Raspberry Pi. If you have made the image you can flash it to an SD Card and boot it in a RasPi. I have tested it by copying [Raspbian Stretch Lite](https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian_lite/images/raspbian_lite-2019-04-09/), [Raspbian Buster Lite](https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian_lite/images/raspbian_lite-2020-02-14/) and [Raspbian Buster with Desktop](https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/images/raspbian-2020-02-14/) to a modified partition scheme and boot it up.

### Create an empty image file

We just create a file with Null bytes of the size we want, partition it and format the partitions in the file. I will use an image with 3.9 GiB (3900 MiB) to be used with **Raspbian Buster with Desktop**.

This gives the empty file:

```sh
laptop ~$ sudo -Es
laptop ~# dd of=raspbian.img seek=3900M bs=1 count=0
```

Create a default msdos partition table on the virgin image and partition it for a **fat32** boot partition and an **ext4** root partition:

```sh
laptop ~# parted raspbian.img mktable msdos
laptop ~# parted raspbian.img mkpart primary fat32 2048s 257MiB
laptop ~# parted raspbian.img mkpart primary ext4 257MiB 100%
```

Now we have to format the partitions with a file system but there is a problem. The formating programs need a block device file from directory `/dev`. Fortunately we can use loop devices to address the partitions as block devices. We will use `losetup` to do it:

```sh
laptop ~# losetup --find --partscan --show raspbian.img
laptop ~# ls /dev/loop0*
/dev/loop0  /dev/loop0p1  /dev/loop0p2

# format partitions
laptop ~# mkfs.vfat -F 32 -n BOOT /dev/loop0p1
laptop ~# mkfs.ext4 -L rootfs /dev/loop0p2
```

Now we have a formated but empty image to which we can copy an operating system.

### Copy an operating system to the empty image file

For example I will use a SD Card attached to `/dev/sdb`. Its content will be copied to the image, provided it all fits to the new image file. I will mount the SD Card and copy the data:

```sh
# mount the SD Card
laptop ~# mkdir /mnt/sdcp2
laptop ~# mount /dev/sdb2 /mnt/sdcp2/
laptop ~# mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/sdcp2/boot
```

The image partitions are still attached from the first step. Now we will mount them:

```sh
# mount the image partitions
laptop ~# mkdir /mnt/imgp2
laptop ~# mount /dev/loop0p2 /mnt/imgp2/
laptop ~# mkdir /mnt/imgp2/boot
laptop ~# mount /dev/loop0p1 /mnt/imgp2/boot

# copy the SD Card
laptop ~# cp -a /mnt/sdcp2/* /mnt/imgp2/
```

If you coppied Raspbian then change device name for root partition in `boot/cmdline.txt` and in `etc/fstab` to **/dev/mmcblk0p1** and **/dev/mmcblk0p2** because the used PARTUUID there isn't valid anymore. On other operating systems check, if they address the partitions the right way.

```sh
laptop ~# sed -i 's/root=PARTUUID=[a-z0-9]*-02/root=\/dev\/mmcblk0p2/' /mnt/imgp2/boot/cmdline.txt
laptop ~# sed -i 's/^PARTUUID=[a-z0-9]*-01/\/dev\/mmcblk0p1/' /mnt/imgp2/etc/fstab
laptop ~# sed -i 's/^PARTUUID=[a-z0-9]*-02/\/dev\/mmcblk0p2/' /mnt/imgp2/etc/fstab

# clean up
laptop ~# umount /mnt/sdcp2/boot
laptop ~# umount /mnt/sdcp2
laptop ~# rmdir /mnt/sdcp2
laptop ~# umount /mnt/imgp2/boot
laptop ~# umount /mnt/imgp2
laptop ~# rmdir /mnt/imgp2
laptop ~# losetup --detach-all
```

That's it. Flash **raspbian.img** to an SD Card and boot it in a RasPi.

### Details

By default *Raspbian* uses `PARTUUID` to address storage and partitions on it. But this is a problem because with a new image we also have new `PARTUUID`. Then you have the problem that the installation does not boot. So we change the partition names to the more generic names `/dev/mmcblk0p1` and `/dev/mmcblk0p2`.

**references:**
[2] [Is it possible to use partition UUID for root-parameter in cmdline.txt?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/78291/79866)

Comment: Isn't `cp` bad for these kind of situations, as it doesn't preserve permissions? I know that `sync` is better with the archive switch.

Comment: @BinarWeb Do yo mean `rsync`? `sync` is for flashing buffers. I have checked that `cp` is doing it correct with option `-a, --archive, same as -dR --preserve=all`. No need to use overkilled `rsync`.

Comment: Yes, I meant `rsync`. And I guess not reading a manual got me thinking it's not possible to do it with `cp`. Why is overkill to use `rsync`? I use it for backups.

Comment: @BinarWeb Discussion about `rsync` is off topic now. I like to keep things as light and simple as possible because its less error prone. `rsync` is mainly made to synchronize complete web sites over slow connections with verify and retry by only copy changed files. That it can also do what `cp` can do, is only a side effect of its powerful possibilities.

Comment: All these operations require root, which shouldn't be necessary for partitioning an image file belonging to a user.