# Backup the system image, and restore with different size of SD card

Tags: sd-card, image

I know how to backup system image, but what if I want to restore the image to a different size of SD card that does not match the one I backup from?
Generally 2 cases:
1. The source SD card is 16G, but I just used like 3-4G, I would like restore it on a 8G SD card.
2. The source SD card is 16G, and I just need to enlarge the space by replace it with a 64GB card, how can I extend the space after write the image?

Comment: It depends on the file system used.

Comment: You can also use tar archives to backup the installation and restore it to a new SD Card of any size as long as the "old" installation fits to it. For this option you can look at [Howto prepare a SD card from a tar archive](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/78467/79866).

Comment: *"I know how to backup system image"* -> The question implies the "how" here was to copy the entire card block for block, e.g., using `dd`.   This works, but it is arguably the worst method that does -- partially because it is inflexible, which is the problem you have now.  However, you can probably mount it and copy the contents onto a card of whatever size, if you read some of the stuff in the duplicate Q&A.