# Moving sd card to a larger one

Tags: raspbian, sd-card, debian

I'm sure there are lots and lots of people asking this but I couldnt find a good answer.

How should i move my  x GB sd card content to the new XX gb sd card since i have multiple partitions?

I cannot use windows because some partitions are only readable from unix.

I did try to clone the card on windows but somehow the new card didnt seem to work well on the raspberry after the cloning and I couldnt even boot.

Comment: `I did try to clone the card on windows` you probably *did something wrong™* - did you use Etcher to read the image and then write the image to the new card? That should work

Comment: I used easeus, took forever, left it under the night xD, when i woke up it said complete, tried it twice

Comment: try etcher - works 100% - zero faffing involved

Answer (score 0):

Working with Raspberry Pi SD cards is painful on Windows.

I suggest using  a **gparted** [Live CD](http://gparted.org/livecd.php) (based on Linux) to modify RPi partitions. You can boot from such a disk without touching your Windows install at all. This is much safer.

You probably want to expand the extendend partition first, and then the logical partitions (+filesystems) inside it.

[image: gparted Screenshot]

Comment: going to a LARGER sd card is quick and painless ... read image, write image, done ... no faffing involved at all

Comment: Is that true for NOOBS too ?

Comment: can't see why it wouldn't ... larger sd card = easy ... though why noobs is even mentioned is beyond me

Comment: im not trying to transfer a clean image, im cloning the SO and all the settings

Comment: i dont have an image

Answer (score 0):

To be completely free in configuration of the target SD Card you can use a tar archive. This is that you first archive the source installation with tar, then partition the SD Card as you like and restore the installation to it. The target SD Card may have any size and any count of partitions as long as the installation fits to it.

How to do it you will find an example with a default Raspbian image at [Howto prepare a SD card from a tar archive](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/78467/79866).