# USB booting from 2TB drive. How do I make a SD card image out of it?

Tags: usb, boot, sd-card

Pi4, booting from a 2TB USB drive attached.

I've finally got the system the way I want it and I'd like to be able to make an SD card image from it so I can quickly recover when I screw it up. Total space used on disk is around 16GB, so it'll fit onto a card easily.

I know I could just buy another drive and clone it, but I've got a drawer full of SD cards I'd like to use.

Just using the SD copier and dd hasn't worked (I suspect it's trying to copy the entire 2TB to the image). I think tar might do it, but I haven't come up with the magic steps to get it back onto the SD.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `dd` with *compression*? Without it, `dd` will try to copy the entire partition to your SD card. You might also give the `image-util` backup a whirl. It's great for creating an image file for backup **from** an SD card - never tried it on a USB drive. Or, you might find [some ideas here](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/make-full-backup-of-your-ipod-usb-flash-drive-and-mp3-players-by-imaging/)

Comment: have a look at what the command line version of piclone does - it's quite simple - https://github.com/raspberrypi-ui/piclone/blob/master/src/backup - there really isn't much to it - of course, it's hard coded to copy from SD card (mmcblk0) so if you change the occurrences of `/dev/mmcblk0` to `/dev/sda` - it *may* work

Comment: Actually, that won't do ... mmcblk0 partition devices are mmcblk0p# whereas sda partition devices are just sda# - no additional `p` added to the raw device name ... so it's a little more complex to change that script, but it is doable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right - **tar** is the way to do a copy of your operating system from the USB drive to a SD Card, but also any other usable tool like `cp` or `rsync` or your favorite copying tool, provided you have an empty image.

There is a way to just create an empty image with partitions you like and then copy the data to it. You can use `dd` to create an image file, create partitions on it, format and mount them. You can find an example at [How to make an image file from scratch](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/78467/79866).

If you like to use direct an empty SD Card instead of an image it should not be a big problem to do it with just partition, format and mount the SD Card.

Answer (score 0):

I use the procedure in [Backup image of SD Card](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/103991/8697) to backup my Pi images.

This can produce a small image, which can be used to make a new SD Card.

I wouldn't try to backup to a SD Card (although this should be possible as I use a similar procedure to synch updated images to other Pi) but you would be better to image to a file, which can be on any media, or a networked drive.