# cloning SD card to another SD Card

Tags: sd-card

after the umpteenth time of hosing my XBMC install and rebuilding, i've learnt my lesson and would like to clone the SD card to a 2nd SD card.

I've found this on StackExchange:

[How do I backup my Raspberry Pi?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/311/how-do-i-backup-my-raspberry-pi)

and now have a .img on my Mac, and have tried to dd it back to a new SD card.

```
Jon:~ jon$ df -h
Filesystem      Size   Used  Avail Capacity   iused    ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk0s2   465Gi  400Gi   65Gi    87% 104902116 16984626   86%   /
devfs          190Ki  190Ki    0Bi   100%       656        0  100%   /dev
map -hosts       0Bi    0Bi    0Bi   100%         0        0  100%   /net
map auto_home    0Bi    0Bi    0Bi   100%         0        0  100%   /home
map -fstab       0Bi    0Bi    0Bi   100%         0        0  100%   /Network/Servers
map -static      0Bi    0Bi    0Bi   100%         0        0  100%   /Users/jon/Video
map -static      0Bi    0Bi    0Bi   100%         0        0  100%   /Users/jon/Music/music
/dev/disk1s1   7.3Gi  1.9Mi  7.3Gi     1%         0        0  100%   /Volumes/UNTITLED
NHQOSX01-Jon:~ jon$ sudo dd if=/Users/jon.england/Desktop/RaspBMC\ Backup/raspbmc.img of=/dev/rdisk1s1 bs=1m
70+0 records in
70+0 records out
73400320 bytes transferred in 15.170466 secs (4838370 bytes/sec)
Jon:~ jon$
```

but i see nothing in Finder. booting off the card i get the coloured splash screen and then this [image: pic of pi output]

any ideas on how i can achieve what i need?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
sudo dd if=/Users/jon.england/Desktop/RaspBMC\ Backup/raspbmc.img of=/dev/rdisk1 bs=1m
```

You are trying to restore to `/dev/rdisk1s1` which is the boot partition of the SD and only 70MB are being transferred.

You should also unmount the SD card first.

You would probably be better using `SDFormatter.app`

Comment: If this doesn't work, your backup is bad.  If it is bad and you make a new backup, take @Milliways' advice and be sure to backup the entire SD card, and not just a single partition.

Answer (score 0):

something is wrong with your image, because it seems too small -- 70 MB:

```
73400320 bytes transferred
```

it seems very unlikely the 4GB (or 2GB) SD card image becomes this small without compression, and even then, 1)it's still too small and 2)requires decompression of some sort.

and, finally, you're supposed to transfer the contents of /dev/disk1, not the single partition, that is /dev/disk1s1 -- only then you'll have the full backup image, as opposed to now, when you have only small part of it.

Answer (score 0):

There is an accessory built in to RPi3 to clone cards. Merely insert blank into a USB holder, place in an open USB slot, and invoke the accessory "SD Card Copier."

It also appears size tolerant: I transferred my 32 GB system onto a 16 GB card.