# Completely copying a Pi over SSH

Tags: ssh

I have full root access to a Raspberry Pi. I'd like to copy its complete setup (full XBMC, configuration etc) to another SD card over SSH. The SD card currently in the Pi is 4GB, the one I'd like to copy to is 8GB.

Is this possible?

Comment: Whatever method you use, beware **[my caveats here](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/5427/can-a-raspberry-pi-be-used-to-create-a-backup-of-itself/5492#5492)** about what *not* to copy if the system is running at the time (whether or not you use rsync, as that answer does).

Comment: Here's a question: why? You need physical access to swap the cards anyway so why go through the trouble copying the system over ssh while runing that very system? Turn off the Pi, unplug the card, copy the content to new card, insert new card, start Pi.

Comment: @Ghanima While it might not be strictly necessary here, there are situations where cloning a Pi over the network can be very convenient (an example from experience would be creating a clone of a Pi that I have root access to but that's locked in a basement to which I don't normally have a key).

Comment: I would take a look at this question and answers
http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/311/how-do-i-backup-my-raspberry-pi

Answer (score 2):

There are various ways how you can achieve this:

1. Use rsync
2. Use scp (see [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/26076/completely-copying-a-pi-over-ssh) for more details)
3. Mount the remote pi with sshfs

Comment: You linked this question for number 2.