# Raspbian on HardDrive

Tags: raspbian, hardware, hard-drive, backup, data-transfer

I'm currently running an apache2 server off my Raspberry Pi 2 with no problems and everything is going smoothly. Recently, my organization (which uses the Pi) came upon a pretty good computer and we were hoping to transfer the pi's data onto the computer's hard-drive itself.

I have previously made micro-sd card backups using the dd command, but I was wondering if that would work with a hard drive and whether I'd be able to POST with that.

(for reference, [How do I backup my Raspberry Pi?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/311/how-do-i-backup-my-raspberry-pi)) that post is what I used to make my sd card backups.

So is this feasible? Using dd to clone my pi's sd card onto my wiped hard drive and booting from it to raspbian without any issues?

Thank you

Comment: Its doubtful that you can boot Rasbian on an X86 computer since the Pi is ARM based, not to mention the boot loader works much differently. What kind of data are we talking about? A database? Some uploaded files? Is it possible to just duplicate the database or file structure that you need in an Ubuntu or other Debian system? I'd want to start clean anyway...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `dd` to image the whole card, or a partition - but is this what you really want to do? The data will be there, but none of the programs will run.

You would probably be better to use `rsync` or `ftp` to transfer the data you actually want.